# Gmail API service account request- Precondition check failed

Tags: node.js, google-api, gmail

I'm trying to work with the google API's for the first time, and when I attempt to make a request to the gmail API I'm getting a "precondition check failed" error. I am using a service account authorization, not Oauth2 user consent. Things I've tried:

1. Authorized "domain wide delegation" for the service account.
2. Ensured the APP is trusted in the G suite account.
3. Ensured service account role is "owner"
4. Enabled domain wide delegation for the client ID of the service account in the g suite admin panel.

This is an adapted [sample](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/gmail/list.js) from the Node client library, but the sample did not use service account auth so I wasn't able to use the sample directly.

```js
const path = require('path');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const gmail = google.gmail('v1');

async function runSample() {
  // Obtain user credentials to use for the request
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: path.resolve(__dirname, 'google-key.json'),
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'],
  });
  google.options({auth});

  const res = await gmail.users.messages.list({userId: 'me'}); // have tried with my gsuite email address as well
  console.log(res.data);
  return res.data;
}

if (module === require.main) {
  runSample().catch(console.error);
}
module.exports = runSample;
```

Returning error with message: `Error: Precondition check failed.`

Comment: You cant use 'me' that would be checking the service accounts email.  You need to deligate it to a user on the gsuite domain.

Comment: @DaImTo I also tried using my userID / email instead of 'me' and got the same result. I have domain wide delegation enabled. Does your comment still apply?

Comment: I had a very similar problem and the JWT solution also applies to the GoogleAuth constructor: `new GoogleAuth({ keyFile, scopes, clientOptions: { subject: 'emailToImpersonate' } })`. The `keyFile` may be dropped in favor of the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env

Answer (score 7):

After searching the dark web for eternity, I found a link to a [github issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/399#issuecomment-108562902) that described how to authenticate as a service using JWT auth.

This is a working version of what I was trying to accomplish:

```js
const path = require('path');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

async getMessageList(userId, qty) {

  const JWT = google.auth.JWT;
  const authClient = new JWT({
    keyFile: path.resolve(__dirname, 'google-key.json'),
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'],
    subject: 'admin@example.com' // google admin email address to impersonate
  });

  await authClient.authorize(); // once authorized, can do whatever you want

  const gmail = google.gmail({
    auth: authClient,
    version: 'v1'
  });

  const response = await gmail.users.messages.list({
    includeSpamTrash: false,
    maxResults: qty,
    q: "",
    userId: userId
  });

  // the data object includes a "messages" array of message data
  return response.data;

}
```

Comment: For me, `await authClient.authorize();` wasn't necessary. My only difference with your use case is that I'm using `https://mail.google.com/` as the scope.