# Gmail API Create and Send Email .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, gmail-api, google-workspace, service-accounts

## Problem

I am trying to implement the Gmail API into an API application. I created a service account and saved the p12 key and the json credentials. I am getting an exception talking about a failed precondition. I think it might have something to do with the message I'm trying to send.

## Code

```
String serviceAccountEmail = "SERVICE-ACC-EMAIL";
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2("./key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
// FileStream stream = new FileStream("./credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); // ! Not Used
            
ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
{
    User = serviceAccountEmail,
    Scopes = new[] { GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom }
}.FromCertificate(certificate));
GmailService service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "Testing Application",
}); 
var result = service.Users.Messages.Send(CreateEmail.CreateEmailMessage(), "me").Execute();
```

## Exception

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Google.GoogleApiException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Precondition check failed. [400]
Errors [
    Message[Precondition check failed.] Location[ - ] Reason[failedPrecondition] Domain[global]
]'
```

## Building Mail Message (does not work)

In the CreateEmail.CreateEmailMessage method I build up a new instance of Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message. Setting the payload and headers. Take this as reference. I am not sure if this is the way to do it but I can't seem to find a way to create a new message. All I can find is things written in Java or Python which i tried translating over to C#, failing spectacularly

```
var msg2 = new Message()
{
    Payload = new MessagePart()
    {
        Body = new MessagePartBody()
        {
            Data = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello world"))
        },
        Headers = new List<MessagePartHeader>() {
            new MessagePartHeader() { Name = "To", Value = "My email"},
...
```

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63316127/gmail-api-service-account-request-precondition-check-failed?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng Node.Js is not C# they are quite different and this probably will not help unless the author of this question knows node.js please stick to the language the author is using to help prevent confusion.

Comment: I do know Node.Js but I have to use C# to make this work, thank you for the comment though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Precondition check failed. [400]

with the Gmail api and service accounts normally means that you have not properly setup domain wide delegation to the service account.

[Implementing Server-Side Authorization](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server)

In your case it may be because you are delegating to  a user that is not on your domain.

```
User = serviceAccountEmail,
```

Is not the service accounts email address it is the user on your Google Workspace which you want the service account to be impresontating.

```
string ApplicationName = "Gmail API .NET Quickstart";
const string serviceAccount = "clawskeyboard-smtp@clawskeyboard-api.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
    
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"D:\api-ed4859a67674.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    
var gsuiteUser = "xxx@YourWorkGroupDomain.com";
    
var serviceAccountCredentialInitializer = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccount)
                {
                    User = gsuiteUser,
                    Scopes = new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailSend, GmailService.Scope.GmailLabels }
    
                }.FromCertificate(certificate);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I get another exception about "client not authorized... using this method or does not have requested scopes" I'm guessing I just have to fix this on Google's side of things.

Comment: Client not authorized is a weird one check that you enabled the gmail api in your project on google cloud console.

Comment: Mhm, I have the API Enabled and stuff but I think I don't have the permissions set correctly  If it has something to do with policy I might have to contact our cloud admin

Comment: Workspace service account setup is tricky

Comment: I asked our company's cloud(-workspace) team to help me look into it, I'll edit the post if I find something that other people might need

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer if you figure out how what was missing in the configuration.

Comment: I got the right permission scopes after asking our workspace team, they set my permissions correctly. I do not know how so I can't include it in the answer 

Comment: Having it in the comments is fine glad you got it working